# How can I get the index from a JSON object with value?

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON string.

```
[{
    "name": "placeHolder",
    "section": "right"
}, {
    "name": "Overview",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "ByFunction",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "Time",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allFit",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allbMatches",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allOffers",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allInterests",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allResponses",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "divChanged",
    "section": "right"
}]
```

Now, I have the value `allInterests` and I want to find out the index (this case; it is '7') of this object in the above string. I tried the following code, but it always returns -1.

```
var q = MY_JSON_STRING
console.log(q.indexOf( 'allInterests' ) );
```

Comment: What you posted is a plain old JavaScript array, not a JSON string. [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) isn't doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You will have to use `Array.find` or `Array.filter` or `Array.forEach`.

Since your value is array and you need the position of the element, you will have to iterate over it.

#### Array.find

```js
var data = [{"name":"placeHolder","section":"right"},{"name":"Overview","section":"left"},{"name":"ByFunction","section":"left"},{"name":"Time","section":"left"},{"name":"allFit","section":"left"},{"name":"allbMatches","section":"left"},{"name":"allOffers","section":"left"},{"name":"allInterests","section":"left"},{"name":"allResponses","section":"left"},{"name":"divChanged","section":"right"}];
var index = -1;
var val = "allInterests"
var filteredObj = data.find(function(item, i){
  if(item.name === val){
    index = i;
    return i;
  }
});

console.log(index, filteredObj);
```

#### Array.findIndex() @[Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp)'s suggestion

```js
var data = [{"name":"placeHolder","section":"right"},{"name":"Overview","section":"left"},{"name":"ByFunction","section":"left"},{"name":"Time","section":"left"},{"name":"allFit","section":"left"},{"name":"allbMatches","section":"left"},{"name":"allOffers","section":"left"},{"name":"allInterests","section":"left"},{"name":"allResponses","section":"left"},{"name":"divChanged","section":"right"}];

var val = "allInterests"
var index = data.findIndex(function(item, i){
  return item.name === val
});

console.log(index);
```

Default `Array.indexOf()` will match searchValue to current element and not its properties. You can refer [Array.indexOf - polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) on MDN

Comment: It would make more sense to use [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) since OP wants the index of an element.

Comment: You are correct, but I assumed, OP would access object after fetching index, so used `Array.find`

Answer (score 26):

You can use `Array.findIndex`.

```js
var data= [{
  "name": "placeHolder",
  "section": "right"
}, {
  "name": "Overview",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "ByFunction",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "Time",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allFit",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allbMatches",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allOffers",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allInterests",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allResponses",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "divChanged",
  "section": "right"
}];
var index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.name=="allInterests");

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 4):

Traverse through the array and find the index of the element which contains a key `name` and has the value as the passed param.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "placeHolder",
  "section": "right"
}, {
  "name": "Overview",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "ByFunction",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "Time",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allFit",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allbMatches",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allOffers",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allInterests",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "allResponses",
  "section": "left"
}, {
  "name": "divChanged",
  "section": "right"
}];

Array.prototype.getIndexOf = function(el) {

  var arr = this;

  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     console.log(arr[i].name);
     if(arr[i].name==el){
       return i;
     }
     
  }
  
  return -1;

}

alert(data.getIndexOf("allResponses"));
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel. There's already [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) that does the same job as your `getIndexOf`.

Answer (score 2):

In all previous solutions, you must know the name of the attribute or field. A more generic solution for any attribute is this:

```
let data = 
[{
    "name": "placeHolder",
    "section": "right"
}, {
    "name": "Overview",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "ByFunction",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "Time",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allFit",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allbMatches",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allOffers",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allInterests",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "allResponses",
    "section": "left"
}, {
    "name": "divChanged",
    "section": "right"
}]    

function findByKey(key, value) {
    return (item, i) => item[key] === value
}

let findParams = findByKey('name', 'allOffers')
let index = data.findIndex(findParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

Function base solution for get index from a JSON object with value by VanillaJS.

Exemple: https://codepen.io/gmkhussain/pen/mgmEEW

```js
    var data= [{
      "name": "placeHolder",
      "section": "right"
    }, {
      "name": "Overview",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "ByFunction",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "Time",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "allFit",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "allbMatches",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "allOffers",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "allInterests",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "allResponses",
      "section": "left"
    }, {
      "name": "divChanged",
      "section": "right"
    }];
    
    
    // create function
    function findIndex(jsonData, findThis){
      var indexNum = jsonData.findIndex(obj => obj.name==findThis);  

    //Output of result
          document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML=indexNum;
          console.log(" Array Index number: " + indexNum + " , value of " + findThis );
    }
    
    
    /* call function */
    findIndex(data, "allOffers");
```

```html
Output of index number : <h1 id="output"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a json object

```
obj.valueOf(Object.keys(obj).indexOf('String_to_Find'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var MYarry=["13","18","77","4543"];
for (var i=0;i<=MYarry.length;i++){
           if(MYarry[i] === "18") {
           console.log(i);
           }
        }
```