# how to find the index of an json Object in an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below

```
let formulaArray = ["(", "(", "(", "2", "+", "3", ")", "*", "3", ")", "+", "(", "12", "/",{}]
 }
```

json object in an  array can be at any index.Now,I want to find the index of json object ,how can i do that?

Comment: please change the data structure to a valid one. objects does not contain items without any key and arrays does not have keys in literal notation.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. Are you asking how to find the index of the `{}`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.forEach()` and then check the object with `typeof` operator, if true, then push it to an array

```js
var formulaArray = ["(",{}, "(", "(", "2", "+", "3", ")", "*", "3", ")", "+", "(", "12", "/",null,{}]
var objectIndex = [];
formulaArray && formulaArray.forEach(function(item, index){
    typeof item==='object' && item!==null && 
objectIndex.push(index);
})
console.log(objectIndex)
```

Comment: I think you should return `typeof item === 'object' && item !== null` instead because if the item in the array is `null` it will use that as the index

Comment: I have added `formulaArray &&` to check if the array is null

Comment: Oh, got it, I misunderstood what you meant, thanks

Comment: Thank You! but this is not working for number of objects,it is returning only the index for the first object

Comment: I have edited the code, now it finds all index and push it to an array

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this SO answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36419269/3902739

It defines the correct structure of an array of Json objects and uses JavaScript functions such as `Array.find` or `Array.forEach` or `Array.filter` as clearly explained in the example provided.

Hope this helps!